# List.Builder giving range error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have added my entire code over here. The getRecords method takes more time to add to the lists and hence my list returns empty at first and so listbuilder fails giving range error and that only range accepted is 0. BTW, Its a Todo app.

InitState :

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
setState(() {
getRecords();
 });
}
```

Getting from the database

```
void getRecordsAndDisplay() async {
final records = await Firestore.instance.collection('tasks').getDocuments();
for (var record in records.documents) {
  if (record.data['phone'] == '1') {
    int len = record.data['task'].length;
    if (len != null || len != 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String temp = record.data['task'][i];
        tasks.add(temp);
      }
    }
    else
      continue;
  }
  else
    continue;
}
setState(() {
  listView = ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    itemCount: tasks.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepPurple[700],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          onTap: (){},
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            iconSize: 25.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                tasks.removeAt(index);
                checkValue.removeAt(index);
                updateValue();
              });
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            '${tasks[index]}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              decoration: checkValue[index]
                  ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                  : null,
            ),
          ),
          trailing: Checkbox(
            value: checkValue[index],
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            checkColor: Colors.deepPurple[700],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                checkValue[index] = !checkValue[index];
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
});
```

}

Scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff8780FF),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [Colors.deepPurple[400], Color(0xff6B63FF)])),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 15.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1.0,
                    blurRadius: 50.0,
                  ),
                ]),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 20.0,
                      left: 30.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Todo List',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 35.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10.0,
                      bottom: 20.0,
                    ),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final resultText = await showModalBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),
                          isScrollControlled: true);
                      setState(() {
                        tasks.add(resultText);
                        checkValue.add(false);
                        Firestore.instance
                            .collection('tasks')
                            .document('1')
                            .updateData({
                          'task': FieldValue.arrayUnion([resultText]),
                        });
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 10.0,
                      bottom: 20.0,
                    ),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline),
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        tasks.clear();
                        checkValue.clear();
                        Firestore.instance
                            .collection('tasks')
                            .document('1')
                            .updateData({
                          'task': null,
                        });
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: listView,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Please help me out. I am stuck with this for a long time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that in initstate you cannot await for async methods so you should implement a StreamBuilder that wraps your listview..
A streambuilder is a widget that takes a stream and waits for the call completition then when the data is ok shows a widget -> your listview

A little example

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: YOUR_ASYNC_CALL_THAT_RETURN_A_STREAM,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                    "NO ITEMS"
                ),
            );
        } 
        else {
            var yourList = snapshot.data.documents;//there you have to do your implementation
            return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(index,yourList[index]),
                itemCount: yourList.length,
            );
        }
    },
),
```

Comment: Could you post your code with streambuilder implementation?